# Local fully connected layer - Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

Assume we have a feature representation with kN neurons before the classification layer. Now, the classification layer produces an output layer of size N with only local connections.

That is, the kth neuron at the output is computed using input neurons at locations from k*N to k*N+N. Hence, every N locations in the input layer (with stride N) give single neuron value at the output.

This is done using conv1dlocal in Keras, however, the PyTorch does not seem to have this.

Weight matrix in standard linear layer: kNxN = kN^2 variables

Weight matrix with local linear layer: (kx1)@N times = NK variables

Answer (score 4):

This is currently triaged on the PyTorch issue tracker, in the mean time you can get a similar behavious using `fold` and `unfold`. See this answer:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/499#issuecomment-503962218

```
class LocalLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_features,local_features,kernel_size,padding=0,stride=1,bias=True):
        super(LocalLinear, self).__init__()
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.stride = stride
        self.padding = padding

        fold_num = (in_features+2*padding-self.kernel_size)//self.stride+1
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(fold_num,kernel_size,local_features))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(fold_num,local_features)) if bias else None

    def forward(self, x:torch.Tensor):
        x = F.pad(x,[self.padding]*2,value=0)
        x = x.unfold(-1,size=self.kernel_size,step=self.stride)
        x = torch.matmul(x.unsqueeze(2),self.weight).squeeze(2)+self.bias
        return x
```